# Замедление работы при чтении каждого следующего файла

Tags: java, производительность

Есть код, который читает данные из CSV файла, используя библиотеку apache csv commons. Метод, который загружает данные из файла вызывается дважды, ему в параметры передается путь к файлу. Имеет место странная ситуация - обработка каждого следующего файла занимает намного больше времени чем предидущего. Причем, даже если вызвать этот метод два раза подряд на одном и том же файле, второй раз все равно будет намного медленее. Намного медленее выполняется та часть, которая проходит по столбцам CSV таблицы. Причем эта часть вообще не взаимодействует с внешним контекстом(полями класса, глобальными переменными и т.д.).

Структура кода вот такая

```
Reader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile.toFile()), 1048576 * 10);
CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(in, CSVFormat.newFormat('|'));
 for (CSVRecord row : csvParser) {
        Iterator<String> cellIterator = row.iterator();
        while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
          String cell = cellIterator.next();
          if (cell == null) {
            break;
          }

          if (emptyCounter > 50) {
            break;
          }
          // HERE CELL VALUE IS PROCESSED
        }
      }
csvParser.close();
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть код этого метода. Вы после чтения файла закрываете его?

Comment: Для того, чтобы не гадать, в чём может быть проблема - приведите ваш код.

Comment: @A K♦
@iksuy  добавил код в тело вопроса